# House gecko for sustainable basement insect control?

Tags: lizards, geckos, habitat

I'm playing with the idea of getting a house gecko and letting it live in my basement to feed on any insects it may come across.

I'd like to keep a small controlled habitat for it but leave it open so it can come and go as it needs.

In the winter however, the basement isn't fully heated. Some but not all and not to as high temperatures as the gecko would prefer.

Would the gecko know to seek out the warm habitat or might it just wander off, get lost & potentially die?

Same question applies for food & water. If I keep a small supply of water & mealworms (or other non-traveling bugs), will the gecko know to rely on that area for sustenance?

It would have access to miscellaneous spiders, beetles and other random household insects (some flying - moths, etc) - Nothing all that large gets in unless let in.

It would have sunlight through windows as well as many dark hiding places. The basement also gets regular visitation.

Came across this as well: https://pethelpful.com/reptiles-amphibians/Lizards-for-Bug-Control - doesn't seem to be a new concept.